Using Flask to run a development server, my pages load but the css doesn't work
I'm making a web app (in development still) so I'm using Flask to create a server and it's been working, but for some reason the CSS stopped working, my file is the same but the server is receiving the CSS and NUL characters:
The CSS the server receives
My CSS:
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav a {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    max-width: 600px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

form {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.flash {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.flash.success {
    background-color: #4caf50;
    color: white;
}

.flash.danger {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.timer {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


I tried to access the file using different ways
(, ) but they all had the same result.
I'll add any other information needed, just ask.

Also add the html code, how you are serving css file and your folder structure
